# Adding integer multiples of $\pi$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I have an angle with a given radian measurement and need to express it differently by adding integer multiples of $\pi$. Is it accurate to say that I can simply add $4$ to the coefficient of $\pi$? It seems like this works in the cases I've tried, but is it universally acceptable? If not, is there a rule I should follow when I need to add integer multiples of pi to a radian measurement?

Comment: What are the cases you've tried?

Comment: What they mean is "add a full revolution". In degrees, this is like saying that $90^\circ$ is the same angle as $90^\circ + 360^\circ = 450^\circ$.

Comment: It might do that for certain angles, but not for all of them. For instance, if you have $\dfrac{\pi}{5}$, and you add $2\pi$ to it, then you should get $\dfrac{11\pi}{5}$. However, $\dfrac{1}{5} + 4 = \dfrac{21}{5}$, which is not $\dfrac{11}{5}$.

Comment: I get it now. What I add to the numerator depends on whats in the denominator. So to add a full revolution to `pi/5`, I'd have to add `10pi` to the denominator - so `11pi/5`. Duh, thanks ya'll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an angle $x$ on the unit circle, it is the same as $x+ or -2pi$, because the $2pi $ means that you are either going forwards a full rotation or you are going back a full rotation. Either way, you still end up at the angle $x$. Since you can do as many full rotations as you want, you cant have the angle $x=x+ or-2pi$, or $x+ or-4pi$, or $x+ or-6pi$, etc. More specifically, the angle $x=x+2npi$, where $n$ is an integer.

Comment: Note that you can write $\pi$ (`\pi`) and $\pm$ (`\pm`).